# mysql - count positive consecutive value

Tags: mysql, numbers

records:

```
ID | NAME  | VALUE
---|-------|-------
 1 | ALPHA | 5     
 2 | ALPHA | 7        //comment: [2 times positive numbers]
 3 | ALPHA | -4
 4 | ALPHA | 3        //comment: [1 times positive numbers]
 5 | ALPHA | -2
 6 | ALPHA | -3
 7 | ALPHA | 9      
 8 | ALPHA | 3        //comment: [2 times positive numbers]
 9 | ALPHA | -2
10 | ALPHA | -6
```

I need to know how many consecutive time I have a positive number so in this case we have:
2 (consecutive positive number)
1 (consecutive positive number)
2 (consecutive positive number)

the final result that I want is show output with a table that tell me how many time in table we have 1 consecutive number, 2consecutive numbers, 3consecutive numbers, ...

so a table like this:

table structure:

```
consecutive number
value
```

data:

```
1 | 1 (we have 1 times, 1 consecutive numbers)
2 | 2 (we have 2 times, 2 consecutive numbers)
3 | 0 (we have 0 times, 3 consecutive numbers)
```

Comment: Maybe, this question doesn't show research efforts... But it is really interesting task. So, I'm personally will upvote answerers `(:`

Comment: no really I tried search on google, and even try many queries, but really can't find how to do it, here I just write the problem, without my test, because I'm afraid that I can influence your answear.

I am working with mysql + php

Comment: "without my test" - what do you mean by that? and how would that influence an answer?

Comment: Since you're working with php, would a php answer be acceptable too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT x consecutive_numbers,
       count(*) how_many_times
FROM (
  SELECT y, max( x ) x
  FROM (
    SELECT
     if( value < 0, @x:=0, @x:=@x+1 ) x,
     if( value < 0, @y:=@y+1, @y ) y,
     value
    FROM table1
    CROSS JOIN (
       select @x:=0, @y:=0
    ) var
    ORDER BY id
  )q
  WHERE value >= 0
  GROUP BY y
) qq
GROUP BY x
;
```

Demo: --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75fa7/8

Comment: It would be even nicer with a proper explanation of what x and y do :)

Comment: There are no `3 -> 0` row... `(:`

Comment: @HAL9000 Tbh, that's a strange requirement, because where does it stop? :)

Comment: @HAL9000  if `3-->0`, `4-->0` etc. ranges are needed, then use an outer join, please take a look at this demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be95e/4

Comment: Hi, thanks for the query, it's perfect! I'm tring to do for negatives values too, but it's not working. Sorry can u give me some tips?

Comment: See this demo for both positive and negative: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bdddd/1

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT peak as consecutive_number, COUNT(*) AS value
FROM (
    SELECT IF(value <= 0 AND @counter > 0, @counter, NULL) AS peak, @counter := IF(value <= 0, 0, @counter+1) AS counter
    FROM (SELECT *
          FROM (SELECT value
                FROM mytable
                ORDER BY id) x
               UNION ALL
               SELECT -1) x -- in case last row is positive
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @counter := 0) var
) x
WHERE peak IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY peak
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/517c0/13)

Comment: `@counter := @counter + (value < 0)` maybe ?

Comment: @HAL9000 No, it needs to reset the counter when a negative value is found.

Comment: Nice attempt, but it's missing the calculation of maximum consecutive positive periods.

Comment: Oh, I missed that part of the question.

Comment: IT WORKS PERFECT!!!
thanks a lot dude!
just one question, only if it's possible, it's possible to output another column as: how_many_nevative_value

without doing the same query with different WHERE clause,
only if it's possible, otherwise I can do do queries, and put in 2 arrays, and show in 1unique output.

Comment: You can add a variable `@neg_counter` and do similar incrementing of it. Once you see the technique I used, don't you see how to generalize it?